# Getting string value from input in query to reveal div

Tags: javascript, jquery

just wondering why this isn't working for me:

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('.box').hide();
  $("#name").blur(function() {
      var value = $(this).val();
      $("div:contains("+value+")").FadeIn(1000);
   });
});
```

Pretty new at Javascript/JQuery, and trying to figure out where I went wrong......I'm trying to get the value of an input (which is the "#name" id) and match that up with the divs in the document (which are initially hidden) and when the string value of the input is contained within a div (in this case, ".box") in the document, I want that div to display. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you have Firebug (or similar) installed? It'll usually tell you where the problem lies...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change `FadeIn` to [fadeIn](http://api.jquery.com/fadeIn/):

```
$("div:contains("+value+")").fadeIn(1000);
```

Comment: Ah, my mistake. Changed it to fadeIn though, and still the div won't fade in....not sure why.

Comment: @KevinStachura Are you sure jQuery is loaded correctly in your document? Put an alert in your document ready handler.

Comment: Ok, I figured out what was going on...I was hitting the 'return' key instead of focusing out of the input field, which would not display the div that I wanted. Apparently you have to click off of the input field to get rid of the focus for it to work. But thanks so much for the help!